Why do the solutions to $x^2 + 2x + 8\sqrt{x^2 + 2x + 21} - 41 = 0$ change when the equation is manipulated?
Starting with:
$$x^2 + 2x + 8\sqrt{x^2 + 2x + 21} - 41 = 0 \tag{1}$$
If I try to simplify without substitution, by moving the root to the other side, squaring both sides, gathering like terms, I end up with:
$$x^4 + 4x^3 + -142x^2 - 292x + 145 = 0 \tag{2}$$
But if I graph these as functions of x, they do not have the same real zeros.  I expected to have more real solutions that the original due to squaring both sides, but I wasn't expecting to have all different solutions. Which part of the process causes them to have different solutions, or is there an error in the algebra?
Graphs of (1) and (2)

The constant term in $(2)$ should be $337$ instead of $145$, and that's the reason for some solutions of $(1)$ not being solutions of $(2)$.

start by naming $w = x^2 + 2x,$    where $x$ being real means $w \geq -1$ (by completing the square).  $w + 8 \sqrt {w+21} - 41 = 0$  So  $ 8 \sqrt {w+21} = 41-w $

since we also require $w \leq 41$  we reach $w = \frac{146 - \sqrt{19968}}{2} = 73 - \sqrt {4992}$

Another way to make the algebra easier is to let $u=x+1$. Then $x^2+2x=(x+1)^2-1=u^2-1$, so the original equation becomes $u^2+8\sqrt{u^2+20}=42$. (This is not really so different from Will Jagy's suggestion, mind---one ends up solving for $u^2=(x+1)^2=w+1$.)

You must have made an error at some point in your arithmetic. And yes, in general, if your process contains entirely-reversible steps and squaring, you should usually have the same roots, plus possibly others.
Anyhow, your idea of moving stuff around and squaring you should first lead to
$$
 \sqrt{x^2 + 2x + 21}   = \frac{ 41 - 2x - x^2 }{8 }
$$
Then we square both sides to get
$$
x^2 + 2x + 21 = \frac{x^4 + 4 x^3 - 78 x^2 - 164 x + 1681}{64}
$$
Then we can subtract the left side from the right  to get, once we break down the fraction,
$$
\frac{1}{64} x^4 + \frac{1}{16} x^3 - \frac{71}{32} x^2 - \frac{73}{16} x + \frac{337}{64} = 0
$$
Or, if we clear denominators by multiplying by $64$,
$$
x^4 + 4 x^3 - 142 x^2 - 292 x + 337
= 0
$$
The error, thus, lies in your constant term.
Ultimately, Desmos agrees with me. If we look at their graphs (original in red, new expression in blue), then we see they coincide:


